# Show the data of each loop product in the form as a value and not as a placeholder in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formarray, formgroups

I am printing in Angular a form for each product using ***ngFor** based on the response of my API that gives me an array of objects with the information of each product.

What happens is that I am trying to have the value of the inputs of each form autocomplete with the product information.

I have tried passing the direct value in the input as **value="{{product.description}}"** but, Angular apparently ignores it.

Also with **[(ngModel)]** but, I double the values in each product and in the Angular documentation it says that it is deprecated.

If I pass the value as a placeholder it is shown in the form but, I get an error when trying to obtain the value with **updateProductForm.value** since the placeholder is not valid.

This is my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard-listings',
  templateUrl: './dashboard-listings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard-listings.component.css']
})
export class DashboardListingsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _apiService: ApiService) { }

  products: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {

    this._apiService.getUserProducts().subscribe(res => {
      this.products = res;
    })

  }

  updateProductForm = new FormGroup({
    sku: new FormControl(),
    part_number: new FormControl(),
    description: new FormControl(),
    price: new FormControl(),
    stock: new FormControl(),
    eta: new FormControl(),
    condition: new FormControl(),
    warranty: new FormControl(),
    package: new FormControl()
  })

  updateProduct(product: any) {
    
    this._apiService.updateProducts(product.id, this.updateProductForm.value).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('Update product!');
      alert(`Update product with ID ${product.id} `)
    });

  }
}
```

This is my component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="updateProductForm" *ngFor="let product of products" class="product-wrap">
    <div>
      <span>SKU:</span>
      <input formControlName="sku" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="{{product.sku}}">
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Part Number</span>
      <input formControlName="part_number" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="{{product.part_number}}">
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Description</span>
      <input formControlName="description" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="{{product.description}}">
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Stock</span>
      <input formControlName="stock" type="number" name="" id="" placeholder="{{product.stock}}">
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Price</span>
      <input formControlName="price" type="number" name="" id="" placeholder="{{product.price}}">
    </div>

    <div>
      <span>ETA</span>
      <input formControlName="eta" type="number" name="" id="" placeholder="{{product.eta}}">
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Condition</span>
      <input formControlName="condition" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="{{product.condition}}">
    </div>

    <div>
      <span>Launched</span>
      <span>20-10-2021</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input formControlName="warranty" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="{{product.warranty}}">
    </div>

    <div>
      <input formControlName="package" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="{{product.package}}">
    </div>

    <div>
      <span>delete</span>
      <span>{{product.id}}</span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button [disabled]="!updateProductForm.dirty" (click)="updateProduct(product)" type="submit"
        class="btn-blue">Update</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

This is how it is printed on the screen :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your form, actually, you are looping your form,

```
<form [formGroup]="updateProductForm" *ngFor="let product of products" class="product-wrap">
```

which is also creating multiple instances of the form with the same Form Group. The point here is that the last instance of the Form Group will affect the data inside the .component.ts form group.

To make data editable from the API with multiple forms you need to use `Form Array` for handling multiple and dynamic nature of forms.

Follow the link to get your problem's solution. [Angular Form Array Manual and Example](https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a)

Comment: Yes, the [(ngModel)] is useful when you don't need to define the form group explicitly.

Comment: My recommendation would be to set each Form GRoup value in Array and just loop the form group in the template it will auto-populate you formControls in the template.